# encoding of request.url.originalstring

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am using a 404 to implement friendly urls in hebrew.
When I access request.url.originalstring I get a string in the wrong encoding.
It looks like IIS 7 is passing the string to the error page with the wrong encoding.
This worked when the site was hosted on IIS 6.
Is there any way to configure IIS 7 to do the same?

Thank you.
-Elad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I worded it for this post I got an idea.
In the web.config there is a globalization section which sets the encoding for request, response, etc.
Once I set that to utf-8, everything fell into place.